# All FirebaseAnalytics setCurrentScreen() events are logged under view_item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm able to log custom events to Firebase Analytics but trying keep track of my custom views following what [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setCurrentScreen(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), [docs 2](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317499?hl=en&ref_topic=6317484) says, all my logs are recorder under `view_item` event.

On firebase's release news I found this:

> In addition to automatic screen tracking, you can manually track screens using the FirebaseAnalytics#setCurrentScreen method. This adds the firebase_screen parameter to every event logged while those screens are visible to app users.

If I want to keep track of my views, Analytics console should show me the `screenName` instead `view_item` or at least `screenClassOverride` in `Value`. Because at this moment I can't do anything useful with that record (not even can apply a filter based on my `view_item` or `screenClassOverride` as you can see in the following screenshot)
[image]

This is an example of how Im doing it in code (inside a Fragment under TabLayout):

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(masterActivity).setCurrentScreen(
                masterActivity,
                FirebaseAnalyticsKeys.SCREEN_NAME_ITEM_LIST_BIG_MODE,
                this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

I could log my views using custom `logEvent()` but I just wanna follow the rules and what the official docs said... so, **what I'm missing, what I'm doing wrong or what's going on**

Comment: Maybe, this answer can help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/42447265/7122018](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42447265/7122018)